# Why this simple css queries does not change background color

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, background-color

I want to test the css queries (`min-width` & `max-width`) and I wrote this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    background-color:red;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    body{
        backgroud-color:#F00;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 600px){
    body{
        backgroud-color:#FF0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px){
    body{
        backgroud-color:#0F0;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So it should be shown like [this](https://quera.org/qbox/view/HjIz2smgrI/responsive.gif).

But it does not change the background at all!

What is it that is wrong with this code that does not change the background color when it comes to certain pixels, while I had defined the related conditions?

I appreciate any idea about this...

Comment: it's just a simple  typo in `backgroud`, ✅ should be `background`. missing `n` character. it should be written like the property inside `body {}` selector. I hope I found your bug :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you are using `backgroud-color` instead of `background-color` that is missing n.
try this code and it should work fine:

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F00;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: #FF0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  body {
    background-color: #0F0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head></head>

  <body></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have u tested this? Because at first the `body{background-color:red}` not seems to be working!

Comment: I tested the code and it is working without any problem you should use background-color in your media queries just like your body style.